# WebView fading edge is a solid block

Tags: android, android-webview, fade

I am trying to get fading edges working for Android 4.1. I've figured out I need "android:requiresFadingEdge", but now instead of a fade, I get a solid block that appears on the top/bottom when I'm scrolling.

```
<WebView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:fadingEdge="vertical"
    android:fadingEdgeLength="20dp"
    android:overScrollMode="never"
    android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical" />
```

Has anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Got same problem on Android 4.0.3

Solution for me: Disable **hardware acceleration** for WebView:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 11) {
    webView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
}
```

Comment: I don't remember what I did, but this makes sense.

Comment: This works, but makes the vertical scrolling choppier. I can't believe Google hasn't addressed this yet as it makes the layout less aesthetically pleasing...